# Problem to animation export in unity using rigify (quadruped)

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unity, rigify

i have a problem with fbx export, particularly with the animations (for the dubts, include my settings for the fbx export)
i have done a rig with rigify (quadruped), the animations are perfect in blender
i import my fbx file in unity and start with troubles

the main movements of the creature in unity are correctly, but the rig seems a bit busted
my precise questions are these

- **rigify have a problem with unity, or i’m wrong something?**
- **same problems someone?**
- **is possible export only the animations without the rig?**
- **how i can resolve this without changing my rig?**

thanks to everyone for the replies!

[image]

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: the main question is that i have problem with rigify quadruped when export to unity.